# Github: What does it mean when the Travis build has failed for a pull request?

Tags: python, git, github

I forked an existing repository and then cloned it. I, then made the changes to the code and then pushed the changes to my forked repository. I then created a pull request to the base repo.

After the Travis build was completed, I see that it has failed. What does it essentially mean?

Comment: Travis will tell you; tests failed somehow. Follow the links to your specific job and look at what the log tells you.

Comment: Example failed job: https://travis-ci.org/sferik/mtgox/jobs/6306535

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like some tests are failing, for example:

```
1) MtGox::Client#buy! should place a bid
     Failure/Error: buy = @client.buy!(0.88, 0.89)
     WebMock::NetConnectNotAllowedError:
       Real HTTP connections are disabled. Unregistered request: POST https://data.mtgox.com/api/0/buyBTC.php with body 'amount=0.88&price=0.89&nonce=1321745961249676' with headers {'Accept'=>'*/*', 'Content-Type'=>'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Rest-Key'=>'key', 'Rest-Sign'=>'ixxn/IrNcHJVB6ztBisOVfUSfm3PUVK3n/YAb2lACdFRrQWFFFMDBTbwIBu8aELgBmgL8j3qqIpY99ozh9FjcA==', 'User-Agent'=>'Ruby'}

       You can stub this request with the following snippet:

       stub_request(:post, "https://data.mtgox.com/api/0/buyBTC.php").
         with(:body => {"amount"=>"0.88", "nonce"=>"1321745961249676", "price"=>"0.89"},
              :headers => {'Accept'=>'*/*', 'Content-Type'=>'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Rest-Key'=>'key', 'Rest-Sign'=>'ixxn/IrNcHJVB6ztBisOVfUSfm3PUVK3n/YAb2lACdFRrQWFFFMDBTbwIBu8aELgBmgL8j3qqIpY99ozh9FjcA==', 'User-Agent'=>'Ruby'}).
         to_return(:status => 200, :body => "", :headers => {})

       registered request stubs:

       stub_request(:post, "https://mtgox.com/api/0/buyBTC.php").
         with(:body => "amount=0.88&price=0.89&nonce=1321745961249676",
              :headers => {'Rest-Key'=>'key', 'Rest-Sign'=>'ixxn/IrNcHJVB6ztBisOVfUSfm3PUVK3n/YAb2lACdFRrQWFFFMDBTbwIBu8aELgBmgL8j3qqIpY99ozh9FjcA=='})

       ============================================================
     # ./lib/mtgox/request.rb:16:in `request'
     # ./lib/mtgox/request.rb:10:in `post'
     # ./lib/mtgox/client.rb:178:in `buy!'
     # ./spec/mtgox/client_spec.rb:211:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

When you submit a pull request on github, if you have travis configured, travis is going to start the build for that particular version of the work-tree. If travis is configured to run some tests and indicate failures (which happens to be in your case), it is going to indicated that the Travis build has failed.

Ideally, you would need to fix those errors in the branch you submitted for pull-request and get the travis build to succeed before the upstream author will approve your pull request.